# bounded set in metric VS ordered spaces

Tags: general-topology

What makes a bounded set in a metric space different from a bounded set in an ordered space? 
Why would this difference collapse for the set of real numbers?

Comment: By "ordered space" you mean a space with the order topology generated by the intervals of some ordering? Such a space doesn't have to be a metric space :) For example, $\omega_1 + 1$ with the order topology: the neighborhoods of $\omega_1$ have no countable basis.

Answer (score 0):

The term "bounded" is overloaded, one could say. Its usage depends on the context. There is even a notion of [bornological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) to axiomatise it (similarly to abstract topologies, measure spaces, convexity spaces etc.). For the reals we can also talk about "vector space boundedness" as well (which coincides with order boundedness and metric boundedness).

We can only define metric-boundedness in a metric setting, and order-boundedness in an ordered space, obviously. The reals happen to be both, and even more pleasantly, its order topology coincides with its metric topology. But this fact alone does not garantuee that their boundedness notions coincide, as we give alternate metrics on the reals that induce the same metric topology, but in which all sets are bounded, like $d(x,y) = \min(|x-y|,1)$. This shows that boundedness does not have much to do with the topology alone.

The fact that they coincide for the reals is partly due to the fact that the metric is algebraic and order-theoretic in nature (its the maximum of $x-y$ and $y-x$, so definable in terms of its additive group structure plus its order) and the order respects the additive group structure ($x < y$ implies $x + z < y + z$, and $-x > -y$). In such a setting I think we can show that metric and order boundedness wil coincide. The reals have just so much compatible structures.